# Error in connecting to mongodb (mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.8.0-rc5) : auth failed, when starting nodejs appserver

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb, I am able to get my nodejs appserver started with mongodb 2.4 and 2.6. I have a requirement to test the latest mongodb, which is 2.8 with our app.  I am able to start the mongodb 2.8 but when I try to start my nodejs appserver, I get following error.

```
    2015-01-16T18:43:51.115Z <warn> globals.js:45 () MONGO URI = mongodb://myuser:password@localhost:27017/test
    2015-01-16T18:43:51.178Z <error> globals.js:45 () #### Error in connecting to mongodb
    2015-01-16T18:43:51.180Z <error> globals.js:45 () { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
    2015-01-16T18:43:51.182Z <error> globals.js:45 () MongoError: auth failed
```

.........

Also, I have created myuser in the test db and authenticated it successfully.  Please help, I have tried all possible ways and with no success. Thank you very much in advance.  (my environment is Ubantu Linux 14.04, virtualbox) One more thing that I forgot to mention is that I am using wiredTiger storageEngine.  I tried with MMAPv1 as well and same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It worked for me on Mac, but on Linux I hit this failure until I upgraded module mongoose from 3.6.x to 3.8.x (3.8.25). That solved the problem for me. You might consider doing the same, at least to rule out this problem.